# gdal_proximity - setting processing extent using -te parameter in QGIS not working

Tags: qgis, gdal, extents, proximity

the default processing extent of many tools in QGIS is the input layer's extent. GDAL Proximity (Raster Distance) is no different. According to the documentation (https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html), you can use the -te parameter to manually define the output layer's extent. The problem is that it doesn't work. The input layer is projected to a planar metric coordinate system, I provide the extent according to the documentation but nevertheless I get "Process returned error code 2". Any ideas what might cause this issue? I tried with 2 different datasets in 2 different CSs.

GDAL Command:

```
gdal_proximity.bat -srcband 1 -distunits GEO -nodata 0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff -te 633000 486000 637000 489000 C:/Users/Jakub/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_yylivC/d36d006521f74df4be1e78c1f186bcf4/OUTPUT.tif C:/Users/Jakub/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_yylivC/6aa539c788a0493f853c43c6a4277c2d/OUTPUT.tif
```

Return:

```
Usage: gdal_proximity.py srcfile dstfile [-srcband n] [-dstband n] 
[-of format] [-co name=value]* 
[-ot Byte/UInt16/UInt32/Float32/etc] 
[-values n,n,n] [-distunits PIXEL/GEO] 
[-maxdist n] [-nodata n] [-use_input_nodata YES/NO] 
[-fixed-buf-val n] [-q]
Process returned error code 2
Execution completed in 0.23 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users/Jakub/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_yylivC/6aa539c788a0493f853c43c6a4277c2d/OUTPUT.tif'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/Jakub/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_yylivC/6aa539c788a0493f853c43c6a4277c2d/OUTPUT.tif
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

The input data information:
[Input layer parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjtq1.png)

Comment: You do not look at the correct documentation. Gdal_proximity is documented in https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_proximity.html and by the documentation the tool does not have `-te` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply.

But wait... Does it mean that the proximity tool does not allow for other analysis extent that this of the original layer? Is there any workaround?

By the way, in this video it looks like she was able to change the extent somehow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3HAvbXbW_4

Comment: I cannot think any other way than clipping the source raster.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that thought? What do you mean by clipping the source raster. I need to extend it rather than clip.

Comment: By the description of the tool I think that extending does not make sense "The gdal_proximity.py script generates a raster proximity map indicating the distance from the center of each pixel to the center of the nearest pixel identified as a target pixel. Target pixels are those in the source raster for which the raster pixel value is in the set of target pixel values.".

Comment: Well it does. Say I've got a point layer of a number of features in a given administrative area. I don't want the proximity tool be limited to the extent of the point features but rather to the administrative boundaries. Nevertheless, thank you for your help. Looks like I will have to handle it in ArcGIS instead, where it's possible.

Comment: How did you rasterize your point layer that you are using as input for the proximity tool?

Comment: If you use gdal_rasterize https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html (Rasterize - Vector to Raster in the QGIS toolbox) for turning the point layer into a raster file, then it does have a `-te` option for setting the extent of the resulting file. Make the raster to match with the administrative boundaries and then continue with the proximity tool.

Comment: @user30184 Well that was unexpected but yeah, I was using the rasterize tool and didn't notice the extent setting. Thanks a lot!